# sprite out of scope because it's local

Tags: c++, scope, sfml

I'm having trouble implementing this function.

//Engine.cpp

```
void Game::createPlayer(sf::Sprite &player)
{   ///Can't get this to work
    sf::Texture player_texture;
    if (!player_texture.loadFromFile("player.png")) 
    {
        //Error Loading
    }
    player.setTexture(player_texture);
}
```

I want it to replace the "creates player in void Game::run but I realize that Player_texture is local to Createplayer and that it won't exist when the function returns.

```
void Game::run() 
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y), "Shogun Master");
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    //Creates Player    [Makes into function]
    sf::Texture player_texture;
    player_texture.loadFromFile("sprites/player.png");
    sf::Sprite player(player_texture);
    //Creates Enemy [Make into function]
    sf::Texture enemy_texture;
    enemy_texture.loadFromFile("sprites/enemy.png");
    sf::Sprite enemy[MAX_ENEMIES];
    for (int x = 0; x < MAX_ENEMIES; x++) 
    {
        enemy[x].setTexture(enemy_texture);
        enemy[x].setPosition(rand_int(100, SCREEN_X - 100), rand_int(100, SCREEN_Y - 100)); //Spawning Point
    }
    //Sets Positions
    player.setPosition(500, 300);

    while (window.isOpen()) 
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            check_closeWindows(event, window);  //Closes Game if Executed
            player_movement(event);             //Moves Character
            attack(event);                      //Character's attacks
        }
        border(player);                 //Border so player does not go off screen
        for (int x = 0; x < total_enemies; x++)
            border(enemy[x]);
        movementUpdate(player, enemy);  //Player & Enemy Movement Updates
        collision(player, enemy[0]);

        window.clear();
        window.draw(player);    //Draws Player
        for (int x = 0; x < total_enemies; x++)
            window.draw(enemy[x]);      //Draws Enemy
        window.display();
    }
}
```

so how would I implement this, so that my sprite doesn't return a white box because it went out of scope.

//Engine.h

```
void Game::createPlayer(sf::Sprite &player);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sprite becomes white box when I implement function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852825/sprite-becomes-white-box-when-i-implement-function)

Comment: I mean, you're asking exactly the same question without taking into consideration the given answer to its full extent...

Answer (score 2):

The documentation (http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a3729c88d88ac38c19317c18e87242560) for the `setTexture()` method you're calling says:

> The texture argument refers to a texture that must exist as long as the sprite uses it. Indeed, the sprite doesn't store its own copy of the texture, but rather keeps a pointer to the one that you passed to this function. If the source texture is destroyed and the sprite tries to use it, the behaviour is undefined.

One way to deal with this would be to make your own struct or class which contains both the `Sprite` and its texture:

```
struct SpriteWithTexture
{
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;

    SpriteWithTexture()
    {
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
    }

    SpriteWithTexture(const SpriteWithTexture& that)
        : texture(that.texture)
    {
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
    }

    SpriteWithTexture& operator=(const SpriteWithTexture& that)
    {
        texture = that.texture;
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then you can return this from your function:

```
SpriteWithTexture Game::createPlayer()
{
    SpriteWithTexture player;
    if (!player.texture.loadFromFile("player.png")) 
    {
        //Error Loading
    }
    return player;
}
```

Now the texture will always live as long as the sprite.

Note however that when you construct your "enemies" you use a single texture for all of them.  To enable sharing one texture between many sprites, we can enhance the above:

```
struct SpriteWithTexture
{
    std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture> texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;

    SpriteWithTexture(const std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>& texture_)
        : texture(texture_)
    {
        sprite.setTexture(*texture);
    }
};
```

Now you can use it this way:

```
std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture> player_texture(new sf::Texture);
player_texture->loadFromFile("sprites/player.png");
SpriteWithTexture player(player_texture);

std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture> enemy_texture(new sf::Texture);
enemy_texture->loadFromFile("sprites/enemy.png");
std::vector<SpriteWithTexture> enemies;
for (int x = 0; x < MAX_ENEMIES; x++) 
{
    enemies.emplace_back(enemy_texture); // construct enemy Sprite
    enemies.back().sprite.setPosition(rand_int(100, SCREEN_X - 100), rand_int(100, SCREEN_Y - 100)); //Spawning Point
}
```

Now all the enemies in the vector share a single texture.  Maybe this matters for efficiency.

Comment: The first draft of `SpriteWithTexture` is buggy: when copied, the copied sprite will not have a reference to the copied texture but only to the original texture. Also, the second version seems overcomplicated to me: you'd better use a resource manager as was explained in the [OP's duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36855842/520217). This way, storing texture is really a separate task and well decoupled from the rest of the program.

Comment: @Hiura: Thanks, I believe I've now fixed the bug you correctly pointed out.

Comment: Not quite actually: you need to fully copy the sprite as well (before overriding the texture reference, of course) as it has other properties than just a texture reference. ;-)